# mobile image gallery where intelligent full-screen, plus pinch-to-zoom and swipe-between work

Tags: javascript, dojo, image-gallery

Within my web site, I'm trying to get a reasonable image gallery working without making totally separate pages for each major mobile device type, or having huge sections of html/css/js specific to each device.  There seem to be a lot of frameworks which attempt to do this already but I haven't found one that does this well yet.

- covers "most" mobile devices (apple, android, blackberry)
- makes images full screen in intelligent way; i.e. based on portrait/landscape (aspect ratio) of image and of device, make image full width or full height
- swipe between images
- pinch to zoom images further than full screen (and drag to pan)

I'm not too worried about the icon/thumbnail starting page of the gallery but doing that well would be a bonus.

Based on lots of googling and several similar stackoverflow questions, I've downloaded and tested:

...dojo toolkit mobile carousel (disables image zoom)

...photoswipe.com but it doesn't do pinch to zoom

...the jQTouch photo gallery ( http://samshull.com/jqtouch-r148/demos/main/#home ) it did not work at all on BB, and images were black on desktop (FF17)

...the Pagination plugin by FilamentGroup http://filamentgroup.com/examples/jqm-pagination/demo/ lets you pinch-zoom but then the swiping gets very confused.

I understand that all the browsers are still annoyingly different in events fired, especially for touch events.  I also understand that once you're zoomed in, there is some ambiguity between whether you're trying to pan within the image or swipe to the next image.  Still, I just have a hard time believing that nobody but google, flickr, and facebook do this, that no other framework does this well yet, or if there is one, that it is so difficult to find.

Does anyone know of such? or is happily using such on their site?

Comment: Cant you just use the first two libraries in tandem? If they are conflicting just modify the root object name.

Comment: two in tandem? neither of which handles the pinch-to-zoom? how does that help?

Comment: "...lets you pinch-zoom"

Comment: Lasso: "...first two" I listed would be dojo and photoswipe, I guess you meant something else plus last one (Pagination plugin).  As I said its swiping was already very jumbled, so loading another one attempting the same features will, I would expect, make more of a spaghetti mess in terms of getting something working and maintaining it going forward than it would for me to just hack on my own on whichever one is already closest.  Thanks anyway for the comment, it (or hacking) will have to do as a last resort.  But the question remains, does such exist from a single framework?

Comment: Hmm everything ive found has been really buggy as far as cross browser support. Do you have the option to choose the library based on platform?

Comment: Yeah that's what I've been finding too, that's why I was hoping to find a good (single) framework to let me avoid that but yes I do have that option on the web server (digitalocean virt machine) so I could use different library for each. I mean I could even re-write my site's start page to funnel apple users to a totally different set of sub-pages, blackberry to another, android to another.

Answer (score 1):

I was after the same thing.  I gave up looking for a single library and went with a combination of swipe.js (https://github.com/bradbirdsall/Swipe) and PinchZoom (http://rtp-ch.github.io/pinchzoom/) , which work perfectly together.  I've tested on android and iphone, but not blackberry (not an issue for me).  There's a live demo of both libraries working together here http://rtp-ch.github.io/pinchzoom/demo/swipe.html so you can try for yourself.

note - i had issues with swipe v2 so i stuck with v1.0